# how to get two (or more) controls to share the same event handler

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I cant seem to find anything on the net, its probably a simple solution. Any help would be great!

```
    private void radioButtonout_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = 128;
        a = (b | dir);
        dir = Convert.ToByte(a);
    }
```

I want another radiobutton to be the exact duplicate of this without rewriting the code, how do I get another radio button to use this event handler?

Comment: This isn't very clear - do you mean you want two (or more) controls to share the same event handler?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's exactly your question. Please have a read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Then edit your question to make it easier to understand

Comment: yes I want two controls to share the same event handler

Comment: there is b there is a there is dir but ... where is radiobutton ? You are not using it at all ?Just hook radioButtonout_CheckedChanged EventHandler to every radiobutton checked_changed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options at first sight:

1. If both controls their event handlers have the same signature, you can just point both of them to the same handler.
2. Otherwise you create 1 method `DoSomething()` which contains the code to do the common task and call it from both controls their event handlers.

Comment: what do you mean by the same signature? i'm new to programming

Comment: @Brendan the same signature means the same return type and the same amount and type of parameters. `void (object, EventArgs)` is the signature of your event.

Comment: thanks, but how do you point a control to an event handler? I don't want to do a method call

Comment: U can do it in designer. When You click a control You can see its properties in properties window. Click on the icon which looks like a lighting bold -> find event -> in textbox next to event type or paste name of Your eventhandler

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly You want to bind few controls to one eventhandler. If all the controls are of same type You can do it like this(Let's assume it's a button):

```
some event_handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button retrievedButton = sender as Button;
  // now you have instance of a button which fired an eventhandler stored in retrievedButton variable
  // and You can do something with that
}
```

Comment: If You want to use one EvenHandler for different controls i suggest not doing this but if u really need this ask me in comment and I'll make suitable edit for You :)

Comment: yes I want 2 numericUpDown controls to carry out the same code contained within the first control without rewriting it, why would you not recommend this?

Comment: Show us some code or be more specific about Your goal because I'm not sure if I understand You.